# django admin inline has no foreign key relation

Tags: django

I have a model like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(MediaFile)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here I have `thumbnail` foreign key to `MediaFile`.

I want to have `Inline` of `Category` model.

I have done this :

```
class MediaInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MediaFile
    extra = 0
    max_num=0

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    inlines = [ MediaInline, ]

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Its not happening.. Here I am assuming to have `MediaFile` Inline to `Category` . What is wrong in here ?

Comment: You have `max_num=0`

Comment: thats not the issue.. its giving me media.MediaFile has no foreign key to category.Category, but I have MediaFile as foreign key to category. When I list foreignkey it should have MediaFile as Inline

Answer (score 2):

Your foreign key is the wrong way round. If you want multiple mediafiles in one category, the fk needs to live on the MediaFile model. That way the inline will work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set inlines this way because Category instance will be saved before MediaFile. Yet, Django wouldn't be able to set Category.thumbnail while MediaFile is not saved.

You should rather have a `CategoryInline` in `MediaFileAdmin` for instance.