# Django edit parent's fields inside child

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, python-3.5

I'm facing a problem with django-admin. I have three objects:

- Description
- Job
- Project

And I want to edit the Description directly inside Job and Project.

Here is my `model.py`:

```
class Description(models.Model):
    short_desc = models.TextField()
    long_desc = models.TextField()


class Job(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField()
    desc = models.ForeignKey(Description)


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    desc = models.ForeignKey(Description)
```

So, conceptually, `Description` is the parent of `Job` and `Project`.

And my `admin.py`:

```
class DescriptionInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Description


@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Project
    inlines = [DescriptionInLine]


@admin.register(Job)
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Job
    inlines = [DescriptionInLine]
```

Whenever I run the django server, I get the following error:

```
<class 'admin.DescriptionInLine'>: (admin.E202) 'Description' has no ForeignKey to 'Job'.
```

I understand why I get the error: django expects the relation to be in the other way.

I also tried replacing `ForeignKey` by `OneToOneField`, without any success.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because inlines are intended to be used in the other direction (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35609183/1529346)).

I think for your usecase you'd better use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance):

```
class Description(models.Model)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        # Abstract is optional but I think for your usecase,
        # standalone `Description` does not make any sense.
        # If not `abstract`, a one-to-one relation will be implied
        # between parent and children

    short_desc = models.TextField()
    long_desc = models.TextField()

class Job(Description):
    location = models.TextField()

class Project(Description):
    name = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Note to people changing their model: Don't forget to `makemigrations` and `migrate`. :)